# Create a mark on an image using relative positioning?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'd like to be able to mark an image where a user clicks, store the coordinates, and then be able to recreate the marks at a later time.  I've got the storing part down but I'm having trouble getting the mark image to show up on the image.

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962930/jquery-how-to-add-mark-to-image) using absolute positioning, but I'd like the coordinates to be relative to the image.

Looks like jQuery [position](http://api.jquery.com/position/) will give me the position relative to the parent, but from there how would I create and position the mark image relative to the parent?  Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
 <div id="container">
    <img id="imgtoclick"></img>
</div>


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#imgtoclick").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var left = this.position.left;
        var top = this.position.top;
    //how to create mark image relative to parent
        var img = $('<img>');
    })
});
```

Comment: You should, at least, be able to get the coordinates from the div, whose width/height is the same as the image. Also, <img> is self-closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @Blenders post but in case your images are nested within positioned elements, you will need to get the coordinates recursively:

```
var myImg = ...

var getAbsoluteOffset = function (el) {
  var x=0, y=0;
  while (el) {
    x += el.offsetLeft;
    y += el.offsetTop;
    el = el.offsetParent;
  };
  return {x:x,y:y};
}

myImg.onclick = function(evt) {
  var offset, x, y;
  offset = getAbsoluteOffset(this);
  var x = evt.pageX - offset.x;
  var y = evt.pageY - offset.y;
  alert('x: ' + x + '\ny: ' + y);
};
```

Comment: That does seem to get the coordinates correctly but how do I then create the mark image to overlay the original image?

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
$('img').click(function(event) {
  var x = event.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
  var y = event.pageY - this.offsetTop;

  alert('X: ' + x + '\nY:' + y);
});
```

Comment: Yes, but not if you add a css position property other than the default one. Hmm, code doesn't look good in comments, I'll post it separately.

Answer (score 1):

You would follow these steps:

1. Give #container this style

   container
   {
     position: relative;
   }
2. Give the image that will show the mark this style

   mark
   {
     position: absolute;
     left: //left from jQuery
     top: //top from jQuery position
   }