# creating custom interactive map using jquery and html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a custom interactive map which will be similar to this one: http://shows.marketart.com/surf10/
the example is developed using flash, and I want to make somthing similar to it using jquery and html5 if possible, the main requirements are: zooming, plotting on the map,

thank you in advance for any recommendations

regards,

Comment: Seems the perfect use case for SVG

Comment: demo using the new Snap.svg http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tEfsH

Answer (score 0):

I see two possibilities:

1- Do a image map and use a image point plugin like [This](http://ipicture.justmybit.com/) with a tooltip plugin, if you need.

2- See this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962930/jquery-how-to-add-mark-to-image) and do with css and use tool tip plugin.

For zoom, you can easy use a Jquery plugin

Answer (score 0):

There are similar jQuery plugins too. For example:
http://www.virtualsen.se/map/